# cannot upgrade Catfish file searching tool

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, dependencies

I receive the following error messages attempting to upgrade the `Catfish` file searching tool:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  catfish

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catfish : Depends: python3-pexpect but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So when I attempt to install the missing unmet dependency `python3-pexpect` I receive the following error message:

```
Package python3-pexpect is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pexpect' has no installation candidate
```

Please advise on how I may be able correct this issue so I am able to upgrade `Catfish` and remove the program from being held back.

I am afraid to completely uninstall and then reinstall `Catfish` as the `python3-pexpect` package is not available and if it is required for the upgrade then I fear I will not be able to reinstall `Catfish` at all.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running 14.04 you won't be able to install `python3-pexpect` on previous releases as this package is [only available as of 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-pexpect).

But as it only depends on python3 you can manually install it on your system:

1. Download the corresponding [deb file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python3-pexpect/download).
2. In the same folder where you downloaded the deb file, open a terminal an type:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i python3-pexpect_3.1-1_all.deb
   ```
3. Finally upgrade `Catfish` now that all its dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: Wow! You are very brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, please mark my answer as accepted and don't forget to upvote it (^). Thanks

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers